# Bootstrap 3 open modal with PHP & jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

As long as I've got the HTML code inside the template, using the code below, I'm able to open a modal window

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".contact-form">
```

The problem is that I've lots of modals in my page, something that makes the page too heavy. I want to bypass this issue using jquery which will open a PHP file and that PHP file, except the relevant PHP code, will load the template for the modal `(I'm using Smarty templates)`.

Any example on how I can do it?

Thank you
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page title</title>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <a href="modal.html" data-toggle="ajaxModal">My link</a>

</body>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="ajaxModal"]',
        function (e) {
            $('#ajaxModal').remove();
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this)
                , $remote = $this.data('remote') || $this.attr('href')
                , $modal = $('<div class="modal fade" id="ajaxModal"><div class="modal-body"></div></div>');
            $('body').append($modal);
            $modal.modal();
            $modal.load($remote);
        }
    );
</script>

</html>
```

For each new link you can repeat this code structure.

```
<a href="modal2.html" data-toggle="ajaxModal">My link 2</a>
```

modal.html

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            Modal

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

For each new page content you need to create a new file eg modal2.html, containing the same HTML code structure.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting error in console: TypeError: $modal.modal is not a function

Comment: I created a file with your exact code, the link works on the meaning that connects to php file which just echo something, the problem is that it echo the text on the same page not in a modal. geek.cmsviral.com/modaltest.html

Comment: I updated the code, put 2 pages index.html and modal.html

Comment: Thank you. Works fine now. Just curious. Even if it works, normalization is to put js code after closing body tag? I tried your way and also moving it just before closing body tag and works fine in both cases.

Comment: Question: "For each new link you can repeat this code structure" data-toggle can be always ajaxModal and change only the link for other modals, or I must use eg ajaxLogin, ajaxContact, ajaxProfile etc?

Comment: Change only the link URL for the other modal!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it working but still I've 6 lines of the modal window in my page. Is it possible:

1. To add those 6 lines of html code somewhere in the js code?
2. To make js code a bit more compact?

https://geek.cmsviral.com/modaltest.html

PS: The form in the modal is ugly as the css file is missing.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a href=".modal-test-form" data-toggle="modal" class="modal-test-js">Login/Signup</a>

<div id="modal-test-html" class="modal fade modal-test-form" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content noradius">

</div>
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.modal-test-js').click(function () {
load_modal_test(this);
return false;
});
});
function load_modal_test(element){
$.ajax({
url: 'modal_test.php',
beforeSend: function () {
$('#modal-test-html').modal({
keyboard: true
});
},
success: function (res) {
$('#modal-test-html').find('.modal-content').html(res);
init($('#modal-test-html').find('.modal-content').find("#modal-test-html"));
}
});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```